# Equivalent to Java's "restricted" and "extends" in C#?

Tags: c#, java

EDIT: I apologize, I meant `protected` instead of `restricted`. I was tired.

Is there an equivalent to Java's `restricted` and `extends` in C#? I can see that neither are in C#, and they would be useful for a current programming project.

Code:

```
using System;

namespace CServer.API
{
    public class Plugin
    {
        restricted Plugin ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and say a plugin did this:

```
using System;
using CServer.API;

namespace Whatever
{
    public class WhateverPlugin extends Plugin
    {
    }
}
```

I want to have a custom constructor that executes some code before the plugin's constructor.

Comment: Um, `restricted` isn't part of Java as far as I'm aware... can you link to some documentation which describes what you mean?

Comment: ..and `extends` is simply inheritance isn't it? (C# dev here.. not fluent Java guy)..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Yes. `X extends Y` translates to `X : Y` in C#.

Comment: Word to the wise: Stay off SO when you're tired. These questions happen then.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you probably want:

```
using System;

namespace CServer.API
{
    public class Plugin
    {
        protected Plugin()
        {
            // This code will execute before the body of the constructor
            // in WhateverPlugin
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using CServer.API;

namespace Whatever
{
    // : is broadly equivalent to both implements and extends
    public class WhateverPlugin : Plugin
    {
        public WhateverPlugin() // implicitly calls base constructor
        {
            // This will execute after the Plugin constructor body
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `restricted` isn't a keyword in Java; I'm assuming you actually mean `protected`.

Comment: Yes, `protected` is just what I meant.